# Hazelcast NTLM authentication

Tags: authentication, kerberos, hazelcast, ntlm

Hazelcast documentation says that there is support for LDAP, thus Kerberos is supported.
But I need to have authentication via NTLM. 
Does Hazelcast support NTLM for Hazelcast members or Management Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out-of-the-box NTLM authentication is neither supported in Hazelcast Enterprise nor in Management Center as of now (July 2020).

Hazelcast Enterprise added the LDAP support in version 4.0 and the Kerberos support will come in the next minor release (4.1).

The Management Center supported the LDAP authentication in 3.y minor versions already. Kerberos is not supported (yet?).

See also: https://www.itprotoday.com/security/comparing-windows-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-protocols